# js-grid , populate select field on demand with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsgrid

I have a jsgrid and I'd like to load data (an array) on demand and populate the cell. This cell should be a read only dropdown containing the values. These array could get up to around 50 items.

My data gets loaded in via an ajax call in the loadData function.
I populate the grid on demand with pagination.

Furthermore I'd like to be able to filter on each of the values in these arrays. The filtering should not be a dropdown, but a textfield since I want to be able to query all arrays in the database.

My ajax calls are working fine, I can load in the data, even to the select field, but it shows as a string (filtering obviously doesn't work either). I have also tried populating the items parameter in the action field. But couldn't make it work. It seems I should somehow be able te load in the arrays into this field, but...

Can't seem to find anything about simply passing an array to this select field and then translate into options. It sounds pretty easy, but I'm really stuck here. Been fiddling around for about a day. I'm definitely lacking in jquery..

At the moment I have this, its pretty useless but still..

```
$(function() {

    $("#taskGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",
        filtering: true,
        inserting: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        editing: false,
        selecting: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageLoading: true,

        pageSize: 10,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

            controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/tasks",
                        data: filter,
                        dataType: "json",
                    })
            }
           },

          fields: [
            { name: "description", title: 'Task description', type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "actions", title: 'Actions', type: "select",  width: 100,
            itemTemplate: function (value,item) {
                       return value
                    }
            },
            { name: "task_status", title: 'Status', type: "text", width: 150 },
            ]

    });
});
```

Even if I return an array with something like `var value = ['just','some','array']` from the itemTemplate function I get a string with these values and no dropdown.

So I have the data loaded in, ready to be parsed and presented. But I am missing the how..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an array into select field, you dont need to use itemTemplate, just write: items:

itemTemplate should return html to work